$\mathscr F\rightarrow \mathscr G\rightarrow \mathscr H$ is exact if and only if $\mathscr F_x\rightarrow \mathscr G_x\rightarrow \mathscr H_x$ is so

Let $\mathscr F,\mathscr G,\mathscr H$ be sheaves on $X$. Usually how should one do in order to check the exactness of $\mathscr F\rightarrow \mathscr G\rightarrow \mathscr H$?

Because surjectivity of morphism of sheaves does not mean for every open $ U$, the corresponding morphism is surjective so I think it is not correct to check the image of the first morphism is the kernel of the second morphism.

Maybe an addional question, because I know the kernel of a morphism of sheaves always define a sheaf, does image of a morphism of sheaf always define a sheaf?

I guess not, hence I guess it is not correct to check if image of the first morphism coincides with the kernel of the second morphism. But then what should we do instead if we want to check the exactness?

See here for the right definition of surjective: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970443/what-does-it-exactly-mean-if-a-morphism-of-sheaves-is-surjective?rq=1
and then you want to say that $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ is surjective to the kernel of $\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$.

At the end of the day you can just check everything on stalks. In my opinion, for a first course, it's fine to take this as the definition of an exact sequence of sheaves.

As for the additional question, the ‘image’ of a morphism of sheaves is not in general a sheaf. You have to sheafify this image.
